# Notation in a Dirichlet Character

Tags: number-theory

What is the meaning of the sign in the notation for these Dirichlet characters?

In the context of specific cases building up to a general proof of the Theorem Primes in Progressions there are several depictions of characters:

In the case of $\pmod 3$, there is the symbol $\chi_{- 3}(n)$. Whereas in the case of $\pmod 8$, there are $\chi_{- 8}(n)$ and $\chi_{8}(n)$. In the latter instances, the values of $+ 1$ and $- 1$ attributed to $n \equiv 3$ and to $n \equiv 7$ are interchanged.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\chi_{-8}(n)$, $\chi_8(n)$ have another notation:

$$\left(\frac{-8} {n}\right), \left(\frac{8} {n}\right)$$

This is Jacobi symbol, and notice that they are equivalent to

$$\left(\frac{-2} {n}\right), \left(\frac{2} {n}\right),$$

and well-known formulas

$$\left(\frac {-1} n\right)=(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}},\left(\frac {2} n\right)=(-1)^{\frac{n^2-1}{8}}.$$

Comment: Nice. What you say also reflects who gets mapped to +1 and -1, while the notes I was reading did not reflect that.